# Zooming to specific layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, zoom

Using PyQGIS with QGIS 3, I am trying to zoom in a specific layer but I have not succeeded. He tried several answers but it doesn't work for me. Either it gives me a mistake or it does nothing to me

This is my code:

```py
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
from qgis.PyQt import QtGui
import os

fn8=rutas[2]
fn8=fn8.rstrip()
fn8=fn8+"\Datos Puntos Qgis.shp"
fn8=fn8.rstrip()

layer6 = QgsVectorLayer(fn8, 'ObrasCiviles', 'ogr')

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer6)#Lo añado al mapa de capas
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer6.id()).setExpanded(False)

layer6 = iface.activeLayer ()

canvas = iface.mapCanvas ()
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas ()
canvas.zoomToSelected (layer6)
canvas.refresh ()
```

[image: example]

Comment: It is possible that your issues are in your paths. You should use Unix nomenclature without any space. This is recommended path for your code: **"/Datos_Puntos_Qgis.shp"**. Fix whatever similar situation in it.

Comment: Thank you very much but the route works perfect. The only thing that does not generate is the zoom

Answer (score 2):

I don't see you actually selecting any data within the layer. If selection isn't important to you, could try something like:

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
layer6.selectAll()
canvas.zoomToSelected()
layer6.removeSelection()
canvas.refresh()
```

Otherwise you could get the layer extents and then zoom to the bounding box:

---

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
extent = layer6.extent()
canvas.setExtent(extent)
canvas.refresh()
```

You are right. I also tried but nothing happens[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried                                                                                                                                       canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()

#layer6.selectAll()
#canvas.zoomToSelected()
#layer6.removeSelection()

extent = layer6.extent()
#canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.setExtent(extent)
#canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
##canvas.zoomToSelected(layer6).trigger()
canvas.refresh()